# Installed Ubuntu 14.04 alongside OEM Windows 8.1 -- cannot successfuly manipulate Windows Boot Manager

Tags: dual-boot, grub2, windows-8, uefi, refind

None of the previous questions or guides have been successful for me after a long day of trying.

My laptop came with Windows 8.1 installed and is UEFI. I installed Ubuntu alongside it and can get into either successfully-- windows by default upon booting, or ubuntu when I press ESC during boot and manually choose the ubuntu OS in my BIOS menu. Otherwise it is always skipped over.

I have used boot repair, rEFInd, and GRUB and have both of the latter installed (and can navigate to them via the BIOS menu) but Windows Boot Manager / Windows 8.1 always takes control upon startup, and I cannot add any other options to it.

Using the "bcdedit.............grubx64.efi" line in a windows terminal says operation successful but then nothing changes.

So, I'm pretty stuck. Here is the link from Boot Repair for you guys:
http://paste.ubuntu.com/9879316/

Thanks in advance.

edit: My goal is to have a menu when I boot (GRUB or rEFInd) for me to choose between Windows 8.1 or Ubuntu each time (and windows 10 tech preview, once I get this figured out), instead of Windows 8.1 bullying the others out of the picture.

Comment: having similar issue but I'm trying with `rEFInd` and also the `bcdedit /set {bootmgr} path \EFI\refind\shim.efi` command is returning `successful` and also nothing changes. Can't confirm it as an answer, yet, but this link seems to have it sorted: http://www.azloco.com/node/197

Comment: Chances are your firmware is buggy. An update might help, but chances are you'll need to use the file-renaming workaround noted in the answer I referenced above. The Boot Repair script can do something similar semi-automatically. This is an ugly workaround that can be undone by Windows, so the best solution is to replace the computer with the defective firmware.